# Windows Shorcuts with quoted command line parameters

Tags: windows, command-line, path, quotes

I have a program shortcut on my desktop with the target set to:

```
"c:\folder\program.exe"
```

When drag'droping a folder on to this I get:

```
"c:\folder\program.exe" d:\myfolder
```

This used to work well for many years, but a newer version of the program only excepts paths with quotes like:

```
"c:\folder\program.exe" "d:\myfolder"
```

Windows automatically adds the quotes for paths with spaces, but not if the paths do not contain any spaces.

How can I force Windows to add the quotes or is there any easy way to change the target to enclose drag'dropped paths with quotes?

Thanx for reading, Needly

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an explicit parameter placeholder `%1` in the target field:

```
"c:\folder\program.exe" "%1"
```

This should work since Windows does nothing else than to fill the drag&dropped file or folder path into %1 ("parameter one") or %2 etc. if a list of files/folders was dropped.

HTH, GL, HF :)